# jupyter notebook cannot open notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I am using miniconda version 4.7.10 and the latest version of jupyter notebook. I can launch jupyter notebook and navigate thorough my folders. I can even open a terminal in jupyter and run python code. However, when I try to open or create a .ipynb fileJjupyter gets stuck and I cannot even stop the process. I am using Ubuntu and I have tried with the latest and previous versions of jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Ubuntu, have you tried with docker? It's a [one-off install](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04) that gives you access to the Docker Hub with a vast array of ready-made, tested applications complete with all necessary dependencies.

In case of Jupyter Lab/Notebook:

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v $PWD:/home/jovyan jupyter/datascience-notebook`